# How to source this hook socket

Tags: components, sourcing

I've been trying to find the name, part number, manufacturer and some vendor for this hook socket. I'm not even 100% sure that is what it is called.

Do you have any information about it? Anything would be welcome.

[image: Hook socket]

Comment: looks proprietary to me, try contacting [e][a][s][y] radio

Comment: I'll try that, maybe it'll work out!

Comment: That did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the component!

- Name: PCB Test Point, Copper, Gold Plated Contacts
- Manufacturer: MULTICOMP
- Part number: TEST-3
- Reseller: http://uk.farnell.com/multicomp/test-3/test-pin-pcb-1mm/dp/1702006
- Datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1680152.pdf

[image: PCB Test Point, Copper, Gold Plated Contacts]

Answer (score 3):

According to this datasheet that I found in a google search, they're calling that a "spring pinned socket."

Unfortunately, I wasn't readily able to find anything similar by searching Google, Digi-Key, and Mouser (where I found the datasheet) for that term.

`- - - - - - - - - - EDIT - - - - - - - - - -`

Upon re-examination of your photo, there's technically no 'socket' on your PCB, just looks like they drilled a large # of vias/thru-holes & soldered in the pins individually.

Based on that observation, I did a little more digging & think you might be able to find a suitavle replacement somewhere in [these results](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/contacts-spring-loaded-and-pressure/1442508?k=&pv69=3&FV=fff40016%2Cfff802cc&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=100).

Comment: I have a box full of those "spring pins".  In our case, they were custom ordered from SAMTEC by another company, and I ended up with them when we bought out their stock.  I used them as temporary connectors for similar RF boards because I could hook a logic probe to them, otherwise I just soldered the RF board to our primary board.  The "spring" factor on them makes them only good for a few dozen cycles.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything all that similar on the digikey link.

@bdegnan, do you have a part number that I could use to continue my search?